# FragmentActivity with ViewPager: Crash on orientation change

Tags: android, orientation, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have used ViewPager in FragmentActivity. I am getting a crash when orientation changes.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    context = this;
    loadInitialData();
    setActionBar();
    initializeUiComponents();
}

private void initializeUiComponents() {
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    }
```

My data is coming dynamically from the database, and I have to call the Sysnctask which is getting the datat from database in onResume(). Here is onPostExecute() of the Asynctask.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        }
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
}
```

Adding FragmentAdapterCode:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new PayeeListSectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PayeeListSectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
    
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        
        return string;
    }
}
```

Adding Fragment Code:

```
public class PayeeListSectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    
    public PayeeListSectionFragment() {
    }
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;
        \\ rootView inflated
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The xml is used is:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PayeeListActivity" >

    <!--
This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
titles for adjacent pages.

    -->

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I am getting the following crash on orientation change:

```
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.walletv2.activity/com.walletv2.activity.PayeeListActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.walletv2.activity.PayeeListActivity$PayeeListSectionFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public  
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.walletv2.activity.PayeeListActivity$PayeeListSectionFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:405)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1767)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:208)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.walletv2.activity.PayeeListActivity.onCreate(PayeeListActivity.java:78)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  ... 12 more
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.walletv2.activity.PayeeListActivity$PayeeListSectionFragment; no empty constructor
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple of hints on the following lines:

> Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.walletv2.activity.PayeeListActivity$PayeeListSectionFragment: **make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public**

And:

> 06-07 11:01:57.834: E/AndroidRuntime(766): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.walletv2.activity.PayeeListActivity$PayeeListSectionFragment; **no empty constructor**

That suggests that you've added a parameterized constructor to your `PayeeListSectionFragment` inner class. Unfortunately, that won't work, as Android relies on invoking a non-parameterized constructor using reflection in order to restore a fragment's state on configuration changes (amongst other things).

If you want to supply one or more parameters to a fragment, you'll have to plug them into a `Bundle` and set it as argument, using [`setArguments(Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29). Have a look at the [`DetailsFragment` and `CountingFragment` in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) for an example on how to do that.

---

This problem can also arise in another situation, which may be less obvious for those not too familiar with Java. If your fragment is a nested class of say some `Activity`, make sure you declare the inner class `static`. For example, in the context of above question, it should be a `public static class PayeeListSectionFragment` (with an emphasis on the `static` modifier). That way the inner class won't keep a reference to the outer class and can have its own life cycle, without any dependencies on the outer class. Without the static modifier, the nested class can't be instantiated without instantiating the outer class, which means Android will run into issues when attempting to reinstantiate your fragment class.

An alternative solution would be to move the inner class to its own `.java` file. That way any outer class dependencies are automatically removed.

Comment: @Vineet: Well, it's either that, or you've added a (non-parameterized) contructor that is private, protected or package protected, in stead of `public`. It could help if you would just add the relevant code snippet to your question. The less we have the guess, the easier it is to pinpoint the exact problem.

Comment: I have added the FragmentpagerAdapter & Fragment code. Kindly help.

Comment: @Vineet: Since your fragment is a nested class, you'll want to make it a `public static class PayeeListSectionFragment` (note the `static` modifier) so that it won't keep a reference to the outer class. Otherwise your nested class can't be instantiated without instantiating the outer class, which is probably why you're getting the error you're current seeing. If you didn't quite understand this, simply move the fragment to its own file. If there are no dependencies on the outher class, that should solve the problem too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved the problem. Can you also tell me the best way to implement fragment dynamically.

Comment: @Vineet: Glad to hear that worked out for you. I'm not sure what you mean by that last sentence, but you're more than welcome to ask another question here on SO detailing the difficulties you're having.